# Is it possible that some hacker is logged in to my computer?

Tags: terminal, network, security

When I type w at the terminal I see myself logged in two times.

[image]

What are console and s000? Is it possible that one of these neos is actually somebody else?

Comment: $ Wake up, Neo. ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nope. Both of those are you.

`console` is where you've logged in (likely on startup), and the GUI started up.

`s000` is the first shell you opened, the Terminal window itself. If you look at the `WHAT` column, it shows the last command run in that shell (`w`), which you just did.

So it's the same user (you), logged into two sessions, one for the OS X GUI, and once in that shell in the Terminal window.

Comment: If you open more terminal windows, they will show up as s001, s002, s003, etc.